# Symbol for the reductive Lie algebra $\frak{u}_1 \oplus \frak{so}_{n}$?

Tags: terminology, lie-groups, lie-algebras

It is common to denote the reductive Lie algebra $\frak{u}_1 \oplus \frak{sl}_{n}$ by $\frak{gl}_{n}$. Does there exist an analogous symbol for the reductive Lie algebras
$$
\frak{u}_1 \oplus \frak{so}_{n}, ~~~~ \frak{u}_1 \oplus \frak{sp}_{n}?
$$
If not then why not? I'm guessing the question is really asking if there exists a "canonical" compact Lie group should with these Lie algebras that is not $SO(n) \times U(1)$, $O(n) \times U(1)$, or $Sp(2n) \times U(1)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that there are nice compact groups here, but for $\mathfrak u_1\oplus\mathfrak{so}_n$ the natural choice would be $\mathfrak{co}(n)$ since this is the Lie algebra of the conformal group. The other one is a quaternionic Hermitian analog.